# getText() from TextView Problems

Tags: android, eclipse, textview, gettext, settext

This is the first time I'm posting something here and I hope you are allowed to help me.

My Problem is maybe kinda easy to solve but I'm stuck... I implemented a `TextView` and a `Button`. The `TextView` gets another random string to show by clicking on the button. 
I want to get the current Text from the Textview but this doesn't give me any value or string or error...

Here is the XML File:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/res"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.20"
    android:background="@drawable/textview"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="30dp" 
    android:editable = "true"
    android:text="generieren"
    />
```

The new Text is setted by the following code inside the `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Resources resi = getResources();

    final String[] ausreden = resi.getStringArray(R.array.ausreden);
    Button b = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView aus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);

            String g = getRandom(ausreden);
            aus.setText(g);

            //aus.setTextIsSelectable(true);

        }
    });
```

Until now I'm trying to reference to the value of the TextView, which currently is shown, by the method getText(). My Code for this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);
    mShareActionProvider=(ShareActionProvider)menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share).getActionProvider();
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(doShare());
    return true;
    }

public Intent doShare() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,textview.getText().toString());
    intent.setType("text/plain");


    return intent;
}
```

Testing my Application in the emulator, the ShareButton only gives the text "generieren" to the Messenger....

I Hope you can give my some advices, to get the current setted Text...

Best regards

EDIT 1, Full Main_Activity

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Resources resi = getResources();
    final TextView aus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.res);
    final String[] ausreden = resi.getStringArray(R.array.ausreden);
    Button b = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            aus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);

            String g = getRandom(ausreden);
            aus.setText(g);

            aus.setTextIsSelectable(true);

        }
    });


}
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);
mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) `    
menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share).getActionProvider();`
mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(doShare());
return true;
}

public Intent doShare() {
TextView aus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.res);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,aus.getText().toString());
intent.setType("text/plain");


return intent;
}





public static String getRandom(String[] array) {
int rnd = new Random().nextInt(array.length);
return array[rnd];   
}
}
```

Comment: post the code you retrieve the intent

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get it, what do you want me to post?

Comment: The code where you retrieve the intent

Comment: You say you get no string at all AND you say you always get "generieren". Which one is true?

Comment: can you post the whole code of the activity ? or the part where you are calling the intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code. It will show pop up to select application to send the text. If no application exist to handle to the `send` event then your app will be crushed. It will also `send` the text showing in the `textview`. Make user `textColor` is not same as background color.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Resources resi = getResources();

    final String[] ausreden = resi.getStringArray(R.array.ausreden);
    Button b = findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
    b.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
        TextView aus = findViewById(R.id.res);
        aus.setText("aaaaaa");
        String g = getRandom(ausreden);
        aus.setText(g);
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_item_share) {
        startActivity(doShare());
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public Intent doShare() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.res);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textView.getText().toString());
    return intent;
}
```

Comment: Here is the full code     https://github.com/shuza/blog-android/tree/master/stack-over-flow-solution      make sure that background color and text color is different

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to create a global property `TextView myTextView` in your `MainActivity` class. This way, you will keep the same reference of your `TextView` within the activity's life cycle.

I think that because of you are retrieving a new instance each time you want to access your `TextView`'s text, you only get the default text you set in your xml file.

Comment: Hello thanks for your idea but if I'm doing this I get a null pointer in the doShare()...

Comment: Can you show me the piece of code where the `doShare()` is called, please?

Comment: The method doShare is called inside the setShareIntend() Method, you can see it in the edited Code...